# default value in jTable for 'options' drop down?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, jquery-jtable

I am working on a simple grid in ASP.NET using jTable (www.jTable.org). It's a page with a list of 'Residents', where there's a field called 'FacilityFrom' populated from a FACILITY table in the database. On the 'Residents' jTable I have a field that is using the 'options' attribute and pulling from the 'Facility' SQL table. I just want a drop down list where the first & default value is '(NONE)' when you go to add a new record.

I did some MSSQL magic and creating a record representing a default value (its field in the database is literally '(NONE)'. Then when populating the drop down I do

```
select FacilityID,Name from FACILITY where Name = '(NONE)'
UNION
select FacilityID,Name from FACILITY where Name <> '(NONE)'
```

I realize it's ugly (I put the necessary unique constraint to make it air-tight), but the query works as expected and puts the '(NONE)' option at the top; but for whatever reason, the jTable is doing some sorting magic on its own and putting it at the bottom! Even if I reverse the above select statements, still, it's at the bottom? Even if I put a breakpoint in the WebMethod called GetFacilityOptions - it's clear that the result is what I want it to be- (NONE) is always at index 0 in the list.. It seems something in jquery binding is making the change?

Anyway, I found the defaultValue attribute on the jTable documentation and thought it would solve my problem, but still it has no affect? The HTML is below:

```
                             FacilityFromID: {
                             title: 'Facility',
                             options: '/Residents.aspx/GetFacilityOptions',
                             defaultValue: '(NONE)'
                         },
```

The code-behind is:

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static object GetFacilityOptions()
        {
            try
            {
                var facilities = BusinessObjects.DataAcesss.GetAllFacilities().Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.Name, Value = c.FacilityID });
                //BREAKPOINT SAYS '(NONE)' IS AT INDEX 0 HERE!!
                return new { Result = "OK", Options = facilities };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
            }
        }
```

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
,  min_id: {
 title: field name,
  options: the options function,
 defaultValue: $('#<% = ddlMin.ClientID %>').val() // where ddlMin.ClientID the value required
}
```